# Android tabview title add 3 textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabview

I am trying to add three line to android tab title but it only showing tow textview when we use custom view and when we use default tab title with "\n" it is also showing two line and after that, it showing "..."[image] , is there any other solution for showing tabview title with 3 lines

We need tab title like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the  `android:layout_height` property of your `tablayout`